# INSERT...SELECT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE without using deprecated VALUES() function

Tags: mysql, sql

**TL;DR (i.e. asking the question first):**

Is there any way to write an `INSERT INTO...SELECT FROM...GROUP BY...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement using row alias(es) in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause instead of the `col1 = VALUES(col1)` syntax that has been deprecated and will be removed from future MySQL releases?

My searches of SO relating to this issue tend to all suggest using the deprecated VALUES() function, which is why I believe that my question is not a duplicate.

**BACKGROUND (i.e. more info on how to reproduce the issue)**

I have a table that comprises grouped records from another table. For simplicity in describing this issue, I've created two sample tables purely to illustrate:

`items`:

[image: items table]

`item_groups` (below) was populated using the following SQL:

```
insert into item_groups (item_type,quantity) (select item_type, count(*) from items group by item_type order by item_type)
```

It also has a unique index on `item_type`:

[image: item_groups table]

Now, let's say that I add two more items to the `items` table, one with an item_type of 4 and one with a **new** item_type of 5. The quantity of item_type 4 in `item_groups` should be updated to 3 and a new row inserted for the item_type of 5 with quantity of 1.

Using the same `INSERT` statement I used above to initially populate the `item_groups` table, I now get an error, which is expected because of a duplicate key (4 of the 5 item_types currently in the `items` table are duplicates of the item_types that currently exist in the `item_groups` table):

[image: insert error 1]

Zero updates or inserts were completed due to this error. To remedy this, we would have **historically** used the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (occasionally abbreviated to *ODKU* below) clause like so including the `VALUES()` function:

```
insert into item_groups (item_type,quantity) (select item_type, count(*) from items group by item_type order by item_type) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = VALUES(quantity);
```

The above `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement with `VALUES()` DOES work (***currently***)...

[image: item_groups after first update]

However, I am also greeted with the following warning:

> 'VALUES function' is deprecated and will be removed in a future
> release. Please use an alias (INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...) AS alias)
> and replace VALUES(col) in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause with
> alias.col instead

Now, I know how to write a simple INSERT...*ODKU* statement to be future-proof against the warning above (generically):

```
INSERT INTO `my_table` (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (1,2,3) AS new ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = new.col1, col2 = new.col2, col3 = new.col3
```

But let's insert more items into my `items` table and then use the above syntax for my more complicated INSERT...SELECT...*ODKU* statement into `item_groups`:

```
insert into item_groups (item_type,quantity) (select item_type, count(*) from items group by item_type order by item_type) AS new ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = new.quantity;
```

I get this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'AS new ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity =
> new.quantity' at line 1

Adding "VALUES" prior to my SELECT subquery, like so...

```
insert into item_groups (item_type,quantity) VALUES (select item_type, count(*) from items group by item_type order by item_type) AS new ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = new.quantity;
```

I now get a new syntax error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'select item_type, count(*) from items group by
> item_type order by item_type) AS ' at line 1

Finally, at my wit's end, I try adding another set of parentheses around the SELECT sub-query...

```
insert into item_groups (item_type,quantity) VALUES ((select item_type, count(*) from items group by item_type order by item_type)) AS new ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = new.quantity;
```

...and I still get an error:

> ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

This ***appears*** to be "progress" as I'm no longer getting syntax errors; however, I don't understand why the column count doesn't match the value count. My SELECT subquery pulls in 2 values for each row and the INSERT attempts to insert those into 2 columns for each row. So it would seem to me that 2 values -> 2 columns should not be an issue; yet it is.

**CONCLUSION**

I'm frankly not even sure what else to try, and I'm about ready to give up doing it this way and just write a simple `SELECT`, store those retrieved values in variables, and then use a simple `INSERT` to insert those values (wrapping everything in a transaction). However, if there is a way to do what I'm trying to do in one statement, I would appreciate anyone who can help me to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

> Beginning with MySQL 8.0.20, an INSERT ... SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY
> UPDATE statement that uses VALUES() in the UPDATE clause, like this
> one, throws a warning:
>
> INSERT INTO t1   SELECT c, c+d FROM t2   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b =
> VALUES(b); You can eliminate such warnings by using a subquery
> instead, like this:
>
> INSERT INTO t1   SELECT * FROM (SELECT c, c+d AS e FROM t2) AS dt   ON
> DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b = e;

In simple words you could use a subquery as follows:

```
insert into item_groups (item_type,
                         quantity) 
select * from ( select item_type , count(*) as new_quantity  from items group by item_type ) as tbl 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = new_quantity;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/HoMLKMfd

Comment: Thank you, Ergest. This works! I have marked your answer as accepted. If possible, would you be able to explain why this "SELECT * FROM (SELECT...)" statement works, but using just the single SELECT does not?

Comment: @snoski unfortunately I don't...I think its implemented on the MySQL code .  That's why it is specifically mentioned in the docs *Beginning with MySQL 8.0.20, an INSERT ... SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement that uses VALUES() in the UPDATE clause, like this one, throws a warning:*

Answer (score 1):

You need a version mysql that is newer

8.0.30 and 8.0,31 this works

> The use of VALUES() to refer to the new row and columns is deprecated beginning with MySQL 8.0.20, and is subject to removal in a future version of MySQL. Instead, use row and column aliases, as described in the next few paragraphs of this section.

so it shpuld work with 8.0.20 too

Besides security risks, with very update come new functions and old bugs are fixed.

Deploying for two Versions is bad, as you need more and more code to support more database version or to simulate functions you need, that you open your code to  more and more bugs and insecurities.

So make a cut and use the latest Version

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (col1 int unique,col2 int ,col3  int)
```

```
INSERT INTO `my_table` (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (1,2,3) AS new 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = new.col1, col2 = new.col2, col3 = new.col3
```

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table`
```

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NLVTM-0k)

Comment: Please re-read my question. This answer does not address the specifics of my question at all.

Comment: it explains exactly why you get an error using a select slows everything down, you always deploy your software and can define which version is the minmal

Comment: I have no issue with any errors using the types of simple statements you provided in your answer. My question said as much. I get errors with INSERT...SELECT, which you did not address at all. It's okay though because @Ergest Basha did address them. Thank you for taking the time to respond. It just didn't address what I asked.